# chart.js : Not all points use defined colors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm making a line graph (with chart.js) of which i have defined similar as shown  below

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Sales Last Week',
                    data: [12, 17, 7, 17, 23, 18, 38],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(1, 161, 216, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(1, 161, 216, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                {
                    label: 'Sales This Week',
                    data: ['8', 17, 3, 17, 50, 10, 49],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(1, 216, 128, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(1, 216, 128, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }
                ]
            }
        });
```

For some reason only the points at x=0 (first values in dataset) render the colors i have defined, the rest render the default gray
Notice the gray color on all points except points with x=0

[image]

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't define your colors as an `array`. Simply remove the squared brackets around them and it will work.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sales Last Week',
        data: [12, 17, 7, 17, 23, 18, 38],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(1, 161, 216, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(1, 161, 216, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Sales This Week',
        data: ['8', 17, 3, 17, 50, 10, 49],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(1, 216, 128, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(1, 216, 128, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: i applied your solution and it worked. Thanks very much. i now see why it failed, since i defined my colors as an **arrary** i should have defined for each datapoint.  ie. my array should have had 7 elements instead of one (that would have a waste of time for my use case). Your answer is way much better . Thanks once again.